# error LNK2019 "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ). Help noob please, i'm new to programming

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "TEXT" << endl;
    // constants:
    const double pivl = 0.5;
    const double pivkg = 13;
    int MaxpivF, MaxobjF, kg;
    cout << "text here" << endl;
    cout << "killograms: ";
    cin >> kg;
    double Maxpiv = kg / pivkg;
    double Maxobj = Maxpiv * pivl;
    MaxpivF = (int)Maxpiv;
    MaxobjF = (int)Maxobj;
    cout << "results" << endl;
    cout << "Text: " << MaxpivF << endl;
    cout << "Text: " << MaxobjF << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Probably you compile Windows application, you should change in project configuration to Console Application. Думаю вы компилируете Windows приложение, т.е. оконное, нужно в настройках проекта сменить на Консольное приложение (Console Application).

Comment: Thank you very much. Огромное спасибо. Хотя я ожидал, что получится exe.шник с парой строк для ввода переменных данных) я просто чайник  :D